# Getting UILabel to line up when some cells have detail disclosure indicator and some don't

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a requirement from our UI guy that he would like all UILabels on the right of a table cell to line up with each other. Not a far fetched requirement, except I am having issues doing it because some cells have a detail disclosure indicator, and some do not.

I have made the label background green to illustrate the issue:
[image]

I am not using auto layout, so far I have tried just setting the frame for the UILabel in the .xib a little more to the left to compensate (i.e. whether they have the disclosure indicator or not) but even then if the frame doesn't overlap with it....it still moves it left. I am wondering if there is a way to maybe have a detail disclosure on all cells but not show it?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happening because the content view for the cell gets resized when there is an accessory view, so the label gets moved, because it's being positioned relative to the right side of the content view. Make the label be positioned relative to the left side of the content view, not the right.